# Erlang AMQP client library

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, amqp

Is there an Erlang [AMQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) client library that is not tied to the hip with RabbitMQ?

I know about [rabbitmq-erlang-client](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-erlang-client/) but I would like something more decoupled... pain when it comes to packaging this stuff for a Debian repository, installation etc...

Answer (score 1):

I know it isn't what you want, but I found that it wasn't too bad to package up the bits of rabbitmq that the rabbitmq-erlang-client needs, plus the rabbitmq-erlang-client, into a Debian packages, and get that working pretty easily.

I have a build-dep on rabbitmq-server though, so it's not the cleanest solution. And it never went into production.

I didn't find an alternative AMQP client for erlang at the time either.

Comment: Actually I wrote one that's about 90% completed: I don't have time to finish it at the moment though.... Thanks anyways.

Comment: Any chance of your library being published as-is for someone to complete? (I'm not sure that'd be me, I'm not in that problem-space at the moment)

Comment: You can try http://github.com/bjnortier/rabbits_foot at your own peril. I've just created it and the example works, but some of the deeper dependencies might be missing